# Are there unix shell tools to compute various word statistics on files?

Tags: unix, shell, command-line

Not the base ones (like wc)... I need tools to build tag clouds, to compute semantic distance between files, to extract word-dictionary from a file, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a broad question...  Have you looked into [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org).  This is an open source library, written in Python, which provides very many Natural Language processing primitives.   This would not work 'out of the box'  ("some assembly required ;-) ) but would allow any customization that you may require.